# Change hash suffix on build using react

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React JS and when I build my app to deploy, I use react-scripts as follow below:

```
react-scripts build
```

And my chunk files are something like:

```
0.cebdafcf.chunk.js
1.fa48de00.chunk.js
2.98b9bea7.chunk.js
...
52.9ca2408d.chunk.js
App.7b21e172.chunk.js
dashboards.f6142b89.chunk.js
user-forgot-password.06d87a22.chunk.js
views.16dc12b2.chunk.js
...
```

But every time I build, the hash suffix are the same, for example, I'd like every build change the hash for App..chunk.js
Is there any way to do it?

I've tried the option described here: [Github Renamer Answer](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/821#issuecomment-306900549), using the lib **renamer**, but it didn't work to update the hash name for all chunk files.

Thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done to solve was: First of all, I had to eject react so on this way I had access to change the webpack.config and after I've changed on webpack.config everything with

```
[contenthash:8]
```

to

```
[contenthash]
```

So, on this way, everytime we have a change on the file, the hash config chunk will be different. And for me, it's enough.

I don't know if someone has another solution, better or simpler. If yes, post to help other people.